# Laravel 5.4 with MongoDB - trying to retrieve embedded documents

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, eloquent, jenssegers-mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection set up with multiple embedded documents. This is how my sample document looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a331ffb854d000f97862f3"),
    "first_name" : "John",
    "last_name" : "Doe",
    "email" : "test@test.com",
    "password" : "$2y$10$fIuECeTqvSUY1g.VPgWxceEzB0/q2OtgDXlm9ZTqwY77U74hVEe6q",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-02-14T16:36:15.079Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-02-14T16:36:15.079Z"),
    "diagnosis" : [ 
        {
            "d_name" : "Asthma",
            "d_isTreated" : "No",
            "d_diagnosed_at" : "2017-02-14"
        }, 
        {
            "d_name" : "Bronchitis",
            "d_isTreated" : "No",
            "d_diagnosed_at" : "2017-02-14"
        }, 
        {
            "d_name" : "Hepatitis C",
            "d_isTreated" : "No",
            "d_diagnosed_at" : "2017-02-14"
        }
    ]
}
```

The parent document belongs to `User` class. However, when in my home page view I try to retrieve a list of diagnosis for each user like this:

```
<center>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        {{ $user->diagnosis }}
    @endforeach
</center>
```

Laravel is unable to retrieve the array of `diagnosis` objects and outputs an error:

```
ErrorException in helpers.php line 532:
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /Users/janisozolins/Sites/patientapp/resources/views/home.blade.php)
```

How can I retrieve these arrays? I'm also planning to embed them even further by adding `Prescriptions` subdocuments to each of the `Diagnosis` document.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the diagnosis array.

```
  @foreach($users as $user)
        @foreach $diagnosis as $user->diagnosis
            {{ var_dump($diagnosis) }}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

Comment: This seems to be the right approach, however, the system now returns `ErrorException in CompilesLoops.php line 80: Undefined offset: 1`. I assume that has something to do with using the wrong array offset while retrieving it?